# Apple obrigando desenvolver app para iPhone e obrigatoriamente para iPad, é isso mesmo?

Tags: ios, iphone

Ontem submeti um App que é feito somente para iPhone, e não para iPad, conforme solicitação do cliente, porém o meu app foi rejeitado por que ele não roda corretamente em um iPad.

Motivo da Rejeição:

> Reasons
>
> 2.10: iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
>   ----- 2.10 -----
>
> We found that your app did not meet the requirements for running on
>   iPad, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad. While
>   your app may be built for iPhone or iPod, it must still run on iPad,
>   at iPhone resolution and at 2x iPhone 3GS resolution.
>
> For information on iOS device screen sizes and resolutions, see Points
>   versus Pixels, in the View Programming Guide for iOS. For discrete
>   code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer
>   Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please
>   be ready to provide:
>
> - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
> - screenshots
> - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
> - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try
>   testing the workflow as described in
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Technical Q&A
>   QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users
>   are seeing.

Eu entendi bem ou a Apple quer nos forçar a desenvolver apps para os dois modelos (iPad e iPhone)???

Comment: Estranho, o Whatsapp por exemplo não roda em iPad.

Comment: Serio? mesmo sendo iPad com 3G (possuindo chip)??? @bfavaretto

Comment: Hm, nunca testei num 3G, só no Wi-Fi. E aí faz sentido mesmo não ter rodado (== nem me deixa baixar da app store)

Comment: É pq o Wpp exige um numero telefônico como forma de registro, e como um ID único. :D Tanto que para trocar de telefone e se manter com o backup de conversa tem q passar por outro processo de cadastro e confirmação de emaik

Comment: Bom, o que eu entendi da mensagem (posso estar enganado de novo, rs) é que mesmo uma app para iPhone precisa rodar no iPad sem alteração, nas resoluções especificadas. Isso não significa que você seja obrigado a a publicar a app como iPhone/iPad. Pelo que entendi, você tem algum problema de resolução.

Comment: kkkk pow, se eu faço um app para iPhone, que pode ser rodado em um iPad, e DEVO fazer a interface dele ser executada em um iPad, vai me dizer que não estou sendo obrigado a fazer para o app para iPhone E para iPad?

Comment: Ele precisa rodar no iPad naquela "janelinha", como se tivesse uma tela de iPhone dentro da tela do iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a Apple embora alguns App's não sejam feitos para iPad, eles devem manter o mínimo de compatibilidade, e oferecer um auto ajuste da tela, para que o usuário possa usá-lo problemas.

Embora seja contra esta atitude da Apple, infelizmente tive que ceder para que meu app fosse aprovado.

Porém questionei sobre app's que não possuem versão para iPad, e nem mesmo aparecem na iTunes Store dos iPads, e não me responderam nada.

Conclusão: Faça auto resize de layout em seus apps para que possam ser rodados em telas de tamanhos diferentes, incluindo a tela do iPad.

Answer (score 4):

O problema ai é de interpretação de texto.

Ênfase nos seguintes pontos:

> 2.10: iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution (...)

E

> Your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad.

Traduzindo:

> 2.10: aplicativos pro iPhone devem rodar também no <strike>fondle-slab</strike> iPad, sem modificações, na mesma resolução que no telefone (...)

E

> Seu aplicativo não rodou na resolução de um iPhone quando revisado num iPad.

Em suma... Alguém lá na Apple pegou teu build, colocou num iPad, e a tela ficou do tamanho errado. Faça com que tenha a mesma resolução nos dois aparelhos (ou o dobro no iPad, se o seu iPhone de testes for o 3GS) que o pessoal lá deixa passar.

Comment: EU fiz com que a tela aumentasse os elementos, ou realocasse proporcionalmente, e submeti novamente o app. Espero que resolva... vou informar aqui se deu certo.